# How to select the column date where the current date minus one interval day using MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a question regarding MySQL query, how can I get the data where the date is interval 1 day I'm currently using workbench and MySQL, I have a module where I need to select all data where my date is minus 1 day it means having interval 1 day to my current date.

Question: How to get all data in the current date interval 1 day

Ex. Today my date is

10/06/2019 so the interval

of one day is 09/06/2019

**I have here my sample query:**

```
SELECT order_date
FROM order_properties 
WHERE order_date >= CURDATE() OR
order_date < CURDATE() - interval 1 day
```

**Query Output:**

[image: query output]

Comment: Have you tried changing to `WHERE order_date=CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`?

Comment: @tcadidot0 yah i solved my problem. i will share the codes

Comment: `OR order_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Answer (score 1):

To solved the problem, I used this query

```
SELECT order_date
FROM order_properties 
WHERE 
order_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND order_date < CURDATE()
```

Thank you.